# GackID on standalone audience deployment

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, audience

Hopefully someone can help me out with a gackId that I've been receiving.

```
An unexpected error occurred with gackId 1372102114-24728 (1131023739). Try again or contact your Salesforce admin for help.
```

A developer on my team has made changes to 3 audiences, committed them to a git branch, and we have a validation build running with those audiences being the only things picked up.

One of these changes is removing the only valid Target from the audience. I know you are allowed to create audiences without them being assigned. I would assume you could remove the only target to an audience as well. I have a sneaking suspicion that this is the root cause.

Here is the metadata for what I believe is hte problem audience

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Audience xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <audienceName>Executive/Accounting</audienceName>
    <container>ProCrewz Portal</container>
    <criteria>
        <criterion>
            <criteriaNumber>1</criteriaNumber>
            <criterionValue>
                <entityField>Contact.$Contact.Portal_Access_Level__c</entityField>
                <entityType>User</entityType>
                <fieldValue>Executive/Accounting</fieldValue>
            </criterionValue>
            <operator>Equal</operator>
            <type>FieldBased</type>
        </criterion>
    </criteria>
    <formulaFilterType>AllCriteriaMatch</formulaFilterType>
    <isDefaultAudience>false</isDefaultAudience>

    //////////there was a target here that has been removed//////////

</Audience>
```

Would still appreciate assistance with the gackId to see if it's a known SF bug or something new that should be reported.

Comment: try putting in an empty `<targets></targets>` ?

Comment: It's foggy now, but I believe we tried this last week and it complained about an empty target tag.  I can try again and report back.

Comment: @cropredy you were right!  Very weird behavior though.  
If <targets> was gone as in my example, I could get it to show successfully deployed via the metadata api by itself, but the destination sandbox would still have the target associated.  When pulling the metadata back down, the target was back.
BUT, if you put an empty <targets> tag like you suggested, it deploys successfully and actually removes the target in the destination. 
Another weird part is that if you pull down the metadata again at this point, the empty <targets> tag is missing.  So it looks like my example... head scratcher

Comment: I'd post an answer but your analysis above looks like it would be a more comprehensive answer and you should post the answer (take out of the OP) as a service to the Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per discussion with cropredy, I tried using an empty  tag.  To be able to test this I was only deploying this one audience by itself instead of with the other changes.

- I noticed that if you remove the  tag as in my example above, and deploy by itself, it **seems** to work.  But if you go to the destination sandbox, the targets were not removed.  If you pull the metadata back down, the  tag is still there and populated.  Even though it says successful, it is not.
- BUT, if you use an empty  tag and deploy, it says successful, and the actual target is removed from the audience.
- second BUT, if you pull the metadata down again at this point, the empty  tag I included is no longer there and the metadata looks like my example above.

So it seems like a few options are available.

1. (this is what I did) delete the audience from the destination sandbox/environment and then deploy.  This will deploy successfully with no targets associated.
2. If you remove the target and pull down the metadata, add the empty  tag back before you commit to your branch. This will allow the audiences to deploy with no targets associated. (now that I know this, this is probably the route I'll suggest to devs moving forward)